# Вывод информации из БД

Tags: php, mysql

Есть код который выводит значения из бд, надо в итоге получить 2 числа, каждое в своей переменной. Следующий код выводит в цикле 2 числа слитно. Первое что пришло на ум - поставить между ними запятые  и $exp = explode(",", $q); 
$exp[0] $exp[1] , но поскольку это в цикле, за его фигурной скобкой выводится только вторая цифра. Как можно вывести эти 2 числа в разных переменных?

```
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error ());


mysql_select_db("user") or die(mysql_error());


$strSQL = "SELECT id FROM tell WHERE idme = '$d' and idyou = '$dd' or idme = '$dd' and idyou = '$d' ";


$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {


   $q=$row[0];


  }
echo $q;

mysql_close();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error ());


mysql_select_db("user") or die(mysql_error());


$strSQL = "SELECT id FROM tell WHERE idme = '$d' and idyou = '$dd' or idme = '$dd' and idyou = '$d' ";


$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
$q=$row[0];
$row = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
$w=$row[0];
echo $q;
echo '<br>';
echo $w;

mysql_close();
```

**Продвинутее будет**

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error ());


mysql_select_db("user") or die(mysql_error());


$strSQL = "SELECT id FROM tell WHERE idme = '$d' and idyou = '$dd' or idme = '$dd' and idyou = '$d' ";


$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
$ids = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {


$ids[]=$row[0];


}
foreach($ids as $id) {
    echo $id;
    echo '<br>';
}

mysql_close();
```

**С каким-то смиселом**

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error ());


mysql_select_db("user") or die(mysql_error());


$strSQL = "SELECT id FROM tell WHERE idme = '$d' and idyou = '$dd' or idme = '$dd' and idyou = '$d' ";


$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
$ids = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {


$ids[]=$row[0];


}
if (count($ids) != 2) {
    die('Надо 2');
}
foreach($ids as $id) {
    echo $id;
    echo '<br>';
}

mysql_close();
```